# Show that the interval $\left[ \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}, \frac{1+\sqrt{-7+8m}}{2} \right]$ contains exactly one integer

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

> Question: Given any integer $m\geq 1$, is it true that the interval
> $$\left[ \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}, \frac{1+\sqrt{-7+8m}}{2} \right]$$
> contains exactly one integer only?

From [graphing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cw7arf7ifu), this seems to be true.
However, I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: It's an interval of length $1-O(1/\sqrt m)<1$ so it will never have two integers, and one would expect almost all $m$ to give exactly one integer.

Comment: Interval of length $<1$ might contains no integer....

Comment: Isn't [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cnuiodrvwu) a more relevant graph? The two bounds are equal only when $m = 1$.

Comment: If $m=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$, then $n=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+8m}}2$; if $m=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2+1$, then $n+1=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-7+8m}}2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the length of the interval is less than $1$, there can be at most one integer in the interval. We now show that there always exists one.

If there is no integer in the interval, then there is an integer $k$ such that $k<  \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}$ and $\frac{1+\sqrt{-7+8m}}{2} < k + 1$.

This is equivalent to $(2k + 1)^2 < 1 + 8m$ and $(2k + 1)^2 > -7 + 8m$.

However we know that $(2k + 1)^2$ is congruent to $1$ mod $8$, so it cannot lie between $1 + 8m$ and $-7 + 8m$.

Comment: You showed there is at least one integer in the interval.  Can you show there is at most one?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner See the first comment by Angina Seng. The interval has length $< 1$ so there is at most one.

Comment: @WhatsUp Perhaps you can add your comment in your answer for completeness?

Comment: @Idonknow Alright... added.